# ios: how to get index of current ?UIscrollView page

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I want to know index of current scrolled page in UIScrollView. I have searched through many sites by none helps.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: similar question it's work for me [link]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132993/getting-the-current-page

Comment: note that the answer here may be as simple as using views.index#of !  **let index = v.superview?.subviews.index(of: v)**  works perfectly in a UIScrollView

Comment: the only wholly correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76058339/294884

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
    //Horizontal
    NSInteger pagenumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width;
    //Vertical
    NSInteger pagenumber = scrollView.contentOffset.y / scrollView.bounds.size.height;
```

Comment: isn't it the strict opposite ?

Comment: Yes..I think the comments is opposite.will change it nw

Comment: wrong, unfortunately. You have to correctly round and encapsulate, or it will (a) often be wrong (b) often crash

Comment: also, you can bounds.width  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76058339/294884

Answer (score 5):

For those needing code (swift) , the UIScrollViewDelegate provides the method, this uses the horizontal example from above

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("END Scrolling \(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width)")
    index = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width)
}
```

Comment: wrong, unfortunately.  You have to correctly round and encapsulate, or it will (a) often be wrong (b) often crash

Answer (score 0):

Use the `contentOffset` property, which returns a `CGSize` that is the offset of the content in the `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Divide it by the scrollView's `bounds.size`, you'll have the "page number".

Answer (score -1):

with the help of some mathematical calculation you can get index number of page
I am sending code for reference only . I have done.

```
-(void)KinarafindingSelectedCategory:(UIScrollView*)scrollView{
    for (UIView *v in scrollView.subviews)
    {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)v;

            float x1=scrollView.contentOffset.x+(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2)-(btn.frame.size.width/2));
            float x2=scrollView.contentOffset.x+(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2)+(btn.frame.size.width/2));
            float BtnMidPoint=btn.frame.origin.x+(btn.frame.size.width/2);
            if(BtnMidPoint >= x1 && BtnMidPoint <= x2)
            {
                if(scrollView==KinaraCategory)
                {
                    KinaraSelectedCategoryName=btn.titleLabel.text;
                    KinaraSelectedCategoryID=btn.tag;
                    NSLog(@"Selected Category Tag : %d",KinaraSelectedCategoryID);
                    NSLog(@"Selected Category Name : %@",KinaraSelectedCategoryName);
                }
                else if(scrollView==KinaraSubCategory)
                {
                    KinaraSelectedSubCategoryID=btn.tag;
                    KinaraSelectedSubCategoryName=btn.titleLabel.text;

                    NSLog(@"Selected SubCategory Tag : %d",KinaraSelectedSubCategoryID);
                    NSLog(@"Selected SubCategory Name : %@",KinaraSelectedSubCategoryName);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```